# Autofac Resolve with TypedParameter always pick up first the same type parameter expected?

Tags: c#, autofac

I want to pass parameters when resolving using `TypedParameter`.

It seems that when *Autofac* creates an instance with `TypedParameter`, it would fill the parameters of the constructor with the first same type of parameters.

Is it expected ?

let's consider an example :

```
public class A
{
  public string a;
  public string b;
  public A(string a, string b)
  {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
}

var builder = new BuildContainer();
builder.registerType<A>();
var container = builder.Build();
var instance = container.Resolve<A>(
    new TypedParameter(typeof(string), "First"), 
    new TypedParameter(typeof(string), "Second"));

Assert.AreEqual("First", instance.a);
Assert.AreEqual("Second", instance.b);
```

Second Assert would fail, instance.b would be First too, is this expected? Why not pass the parameters array in `TypedParameter` as the parameter list of Constructor?

`NamedParameter` could resolve this case, but I would like to know the expected behavior or purpose of `TypedParameter`, and what kind of case that `NamedParameter` could not support but `TypedParameter` does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `TypedParameter` will match with the specified type no matter the order it was specified.

You can use a `PositionalParameter` to match a parameter with a specific position

```
var instance = container.Resolve<A>(
                   new PositionalParameter(1, "First"),
                   new PositionalParameter(2, "Second")
                );
```

you can also imagine a helper method which help creating the parameters

```
public static class PositionalParameterExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<PositionalParameter> From(params Object[] args)
    {
        return args.Select((o, i) => new PositionalParameter(i, o)); 
    }
}
```

which will be used like this :

```
var instance = container.Resolve<A>(PositionalParameterExtensions.From("first", "second"));
```

By the way if you want to match with parameter of the same type you can use `NamedParameter`

```
var instance = container.Resolve<A>(
                   new NamedParameter("a", "First"),
                   new NamedParameter("b", "Second")
                );
```

For the second part of the question, `Parameter` can be supplied by module and to all resolve operation. It could make sense to have a parameter that will be called each time a specific type is requested no matter the name of the parameter. It is quite common for me to use `TypedParameter` and I almost never use `NamedParameter`

Comment: The positional parameters index (position) is zero-based https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/9130C5CD.htm